# How to handle multiple ajax calls both individually and a final result

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am making ajax calls to get html data back and append it to my container. I also need the html to be rendered in a specific order. I am trying to take the approach of loading everything, then re-ordering as necessary but am running into difficulty getting the calls to resolve in order (i.e. render, then order html).

Code (edited for brevity):

```
var components = ["comp1","comp2","comp3"];

function setup() {
    var deferredComponentAdds = [];
    $.each(components, function (i, componentId) {
        deferredComponentAdds.push(
            addComponent(componentId)
        );
    });
    $.when.apply($, deferredComponentAdds).then(fixComponentOrder());
}

function addComponent(componentName) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",   
        url: "/LoadViewComponent?viewComponent=" + componentName,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#components').append(data);
        }
    });
}

function fixComponentOrder() { /* ordering logic */ }
```

There are two issues I am having. First, the fixComponentOrder() is being called before the addComponent().success result is processing. Second, the fixComponentOrder() is being called after each addComponent() call (this doesn't break anything, but it is needless).

What I need is for the addComponent() to be called and resolve the success of all calls, then after all of those are called and resolved, call the fixComponentOrder() once at the end.

I can alternatively just throw fixComponentOrder() in my success function, but then I still have the second issue of it being called each time which is non-optimal.

Thanks,

Jeff

Comment: Check out Promises:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Promise is exactly what you need

Comment: Using promises gave me the same ordering issue. Could be me using them wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to do a similar thing recently

```
var arrOfObj = []
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/LoadViewComponent?viewComponent=" + componentName,
  success: function (data) {
    arrOfObj.push(data)
    render()
  }
});


render(){
  var ordering = { 'Shirts': 0, 'Pants and Shorts': 1, 'Hats': 2, 'Accessories': 3, }
  $('#components').empty()
  arrOfObj.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (ordering[a.name] - ordering[b.name]) || a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
  }).forEach(function (obj) {
    $('#components').append(obj);
  });
}
```

Just make sure the ordering keys matches the component's name. I modified the code i am using, so make sure to test this before using :)

Comment: Since I'm calling the ajax in a loop I end up calling render() multiple times which gives me duplicates.

Comment: That's why I run $('#components').empty() at the beginning of render(). it's not the most elegant way to do it. but its quick and it works.

Comment: Ok, yeah I skipped that part ;). I'd rather just call the sort function multiple times and have it do nothing which is what I ended up doing for now. Thanks for this option though, might be a good fallback for someone.

Answer (score 4):

I didnt test it yet but the logic should work using promise

We execute `addComponent()` once it resolve we execute another function

```
 const addComponent = componentName => { 
    return new Promise(resolve =>{
        console.log("Hello1")
        return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",   
        url: "/LoadViewComponent?viewComponent=" + componentName,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#components').append(data);
          resolve()
        }
         });  
       })
    }

    function fixComponentOrder(){
    return addComponent(componentName).then(()=>{/*Your next function to execute*/})
    }

     fixComponentOrder()
```

Once `fixComponentOrder()` get executed , it will start by executing `addComponent()` and once it resolve it will execute what ever function you executed in the `then`